# Update GNU GRUB

Tags: 14.04, grub2, system-installation

I just have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a partition on which I previously had Ubuntu 12.04.
When I restarted the laptop, the GRUB dual boot menu hasn't updated I among the OS's I have it still shows the Ubuntu 12.04 OS but not the Ubuntu 14.04.
Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: have you tried `update-grub`

Comment: exactly, just trying that while I am in another OS

Answer (score 2):

Boot into either Ubuntu and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

That should generate a new grub config file with your newly installed OS. It should appear next time you reboot.

If it doesn't, run this as well:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

That will install grub in the MBR of your first hard drive. Change `/dev/sda` accordingly if you want to install it elsewhere.